# Space filling with circles of unequal size

Tags: javascript, ruby, layout, geometry

Here is my problem:

- I have a bunch of circles that I need to display inside a canvas.
- There are an arbitrary number of circles, each with a predefined radius.
- The summed area of circles is always smaller than the area of the canvas.

I want to position the circles so that they take up the maximal space available inside the canvas, without touching each other. My goal is to achieve a visually pleasing effect where the circles appear well distributed inside the canvas. I don't know if this is really "space filling", as my goal is not to *minimize* the distance between elements, but rather to *maximize* it.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Circles]

My first "brute force" idea was the following:

1. For each circle: calculate the shortest distance between its border and each other circle's border; sum all of these distances, call that X.
2. Calculate the sum of all X's.
3. Randomly change the distances between the circles.
4. Redo 1-3 for a preset number of iterations and take the maximal value obtained at step (2).

However, this does not seem elegant; I'm sure there is a better way to do it. Is there any existing algorithm to achieve such a layout? Is there any existing library that I could use (JavaScript or Ruby) to achieve this?

**Edit**

Here is a [Javascript version](https://gist.github.com/2089431) of the accepted answer, which uses Raphael to draw the circles.

Comment: Not circles, but http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/1811

Comment: louism, check out Kris' answer! The images look awesome -- I think you should accept that one. @KrisVanBael, how about posting the code on GitHub?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try to insert sphere after sphere (largest first). Each one is added in the largest available space, with some random jitter.

One relatively easy way to find (more or less) the largest available space, is to imagine a grid of points on your view and store for each grid point (in a 2D array) the closest distance to any item: edge or sphere, whichever is closest. This array is updated as each new sphere is added.

To add a new sphere, just take the grid point with highest distance and apply some random jitter (you actually know how much you can jitter, because you know the distance to the closest item). (I would randomize not more than (d-r)/2 where d is the distance in the array and r is the radius of the sphere to add.

Updating this array after adding another circle is no rocket science: you calculate for each grid point the distance to newly added sphere and replace the stored value if that was larger.

It is possible that your grid is too coarse, and you can't add any more circle (when the 2D array contains no distances larger than the radius of the circle to add). Then you have to increase (e.g. double) the grid resolution before continuing.

Here are some result of this implementation (it took me about 100 lines of code)

- 100 Circles of varying size

[image: 100 circles of varying size]

- 500 Circles of varying size

[image: 500 circles of varying size]

- 100 Circles of same size

[image]

And here is some rough C++ code (just the algorithm, don't expect this to compile)

```
    // INITIALIZATION

    // Dimension of canvas
    float width = 768;
    float height = 1004;

    // The algorithm creates a grid on the canvas
    float gridSize=10;

    int gridColumns, gridRows;
    float *dist;

    void initDistances()
    {
      // Determine grid dimensions and allocate array
      gridColumns = width/gridSize;
      gridRows = height/gridSize;

      // We store a 2D array as a 1D array:
      dist = new float[ gridColumns * gridRows ];

      // Init dist array with shortest distances to the edges
      float y = gridSize/2.0;
      for (int row=0; row<gridRows; row++)
      {
        float distanceFromTop = y;
        float distanceFromBottom = height-y;
        for (int col=0; col<gridColumns; col++)
        {
          int i = row*gridColumns+col;
          dist[i]=(distanceFromTop<distanceFromBottom?distanceFromTop:distanceFromBottom);
        }
        y+=gridSize;
      }
      float x = gridSize/2.0;
      for (int col=0; col<gridColumns; col++)
      {
        float distanceFromLeft = x;
        float distanceFromRight = width-x;
        for (int row=0; row<gridRows; row++)
        {
          int i = row*gridColumns+col;
          if (dist[i]>distanceFromLeft) dist[i] = distanceFromLeft;
          if (dist[i]>distanceFromRight) dist[i] = distanceFromRight;
        }
        x+=gridSize;
      }
    }

    void drawCircles()
    {
      for (int circle = 0; circle<getNrOfCircles(); circle++)
      {
        // We assume circles are sorted large to small!
        float radius = getRadiusOfCircle( circle ); 

        // Find gridpoint with largest distance from anything
        int i=0;
        int maxR = 0;
        int maxC = 0;
        float maxDist = dist[0];

        for (int r=0; r<gridRows; r++) 
          for (int c=0; c<gridColumns; c++)
          {
            if (maxDist<dist[i]) {
              maxR= r; maxC= c; maxDist = dist[i];
            }
            i++;
          }

        // Calculate position of grid point
        float x = gridSize/2.0 + maxC*gridSize;
        float y = gridSize/2.0 + maxR*gridSize;

        // Apply some random Jitter
        float offset = (maxDist-radius)/2.0;
        x += (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 0.5) * 2 * offset;
        y += (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX - 0.5) * 2 * offset;


        drawCircle(x,y,radius);


        // Update Distance array with new circle;
        i=0;
        float yy = gridSize/2.0;
        for (int r=0; r<gridRows; r++)
        {
          float xx = gridSize/2.0;
          for (int c=0; c<gridColumns; c++)
          {
            float d2 = (xx-x)*(xx-x)+(yy-y)*(yy-y);

            // Naive implementation
            // float d = sqrt(d2) - radius;
            // if (dist[i]>d) dist[i] = d;

            // Optimized implementation (no unnecessary sqrt)
            float prev2 = dist[i]+radius;
            prev2 *= prev2;
            if (prev2 > d2)
            {
              float d = sqrt(d2) - radius;
              if (dist[i]>d) dist[i] = d;
            }



            xx += gridSize;
            i++;
          }
          yy += gridSize;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I like it, +1. I think this will likely be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks you Alex. But since Louism didn't accept my answer yet, I just went along and implemented it.

Comment: Very nice Kris, that's great! Do you mind posting the code on Git?

Comment: I posted the relevant bits of my C++ project. It was a rather quick&dirty proof of concept of the algorithm though, so it's not very clean.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, Kris. I'll award you the bounty as soon as SA [lets me do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours).

Comment: Nice. Is it possible that you forgot to sort radius from large to small?

Comment: What's the stop condition when the number of circles is too large? I.e. no more circles fit. `dist[i] < 0` for all `i`?

Comment: If `dist[i] < radius` for all `i`, then the algorithm can no longer guarantee that the next circle (with radius `radius`) won't overlap previous circles. (Which doesn't mean that there isn't a solution. This algorithm is simply not suited for solving tight nesting challenges).

Comment: It is an old question, but for those wondering, this is similar to the poisson disc sampling, but with a twist: the distance between points would **radius_1 + radius_2 + offset**. Robert Bridson has given a [nice algorithm](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf) for the simple case, which can be extended for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some application of [force-directed layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29) would be useful.

Comment: This solution would be the best for animated layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is just to "achieve a pleasing effect", not solve a math problem, you should try the simplest algorithm which could work first and see if it looks good. There should be no need to use very complex math.

I understand that you want the spheres to "fill" the available space, not leaving large empty areas while other areas are crowded. You also want the layout to appear random -- not lined up on a grid or anything like that.

The obvious, dead-simple way to achieve that is simply to place the spheres one by one, in random locations. If one lands on top of an already-placed sphere, generate another random location until you find one where it fits.

It appears there are about 40 spheres in the image shown. The chances of 40 spheres *all* landing in the same area of the image, leaving the rest of the image empty, is very, very small. As the number of spheres increases, the chances of getting a very unbalanced layout will become close to zero.

Try that first and see if it meets your needs. If it is not "even" enough, you should be able to use some very simple math to bias the randomly chosen locations in favor of choosing empty areas. There should be no need to use complex algorithms.

Comment: +1 for starting simple. But random really doesn't look nice. You did inspire me to edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's good advice to start. I just tried random non-overlapping locations and it's already better than manually positioning them, but still far from the visual effect I want to achieve. I'll post some updates as I try other solutions.